# Regex to match any set of numbers except the 10 digit numbers starting with 7

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture all numbers(any no.of digits) except the 10 digit numbers starting with 7.

71234567890 - should match
7123456789 - should not match
1234567890- should match

Comment: Have you tired anything yet ? Post your attempt.

Comment: I wonder why some reputed users urge for **OP's attempt** and some plainly neglect it.

Comment: Mr.noob, your regex works just fine. Thanks. By the way, I'm still noob in regular expressions so trying to learn.

Comment: More readable is to write two regexps, one for any string of digits and another for ten digits starting with 7. Then use /first/ && !/second/.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern

```
/7\d{9}|(\d+)/
 ^^^^^^           MATCH 10-DIGIT NUMBER STARTING WITH SEVEN, DO NOT CAPTURE
       ^          --OR--
        ^^^^^     MATCH OTHER SEQUENCES OF DIGITS AND DO CAPTURE
```

This will match the 10-digit number starting with 7 but **not** capture it; otherwise, it will match the sequence of digits and capture it.

Now

```
'7123456789'.match(regexp)
["7123456789", undefined]

'1234567890'.match(regexp)
["1234567890", "1234567890"]
```

In other words, the captured string will be found in the second element of the array returned by `match`.

If you want to anchor this to the beginning and end of the string, then

```
/^7\d{9}$|(^\d+$)/
```

You could also do this with a negative look-ahead, as suggested in the comments, but it's not needed here and could be a bit of a stretch for beginning regexpers.

Comment: On something as simple as this, it's faster to put the logic into the regex than having to check for undefined via the language.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:(?:^|\D)(7\d{1,8}|7\d{10,})(?:\D|$))
```

See the [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/pI8iG3/1)

Comment: Besides seeming overcomplicated, your own example fails to match on `1234567890` as it should.

Comment: 1234567890 does not start with 7.

Comment: Umm, in his question he says, "1234567890- should match".

Comment: well both question caption and details say 'Regex to match any set of numbers except the 10 digit numbers starting with 7', besides that if the third one should match because of the 7 in the middle then the second line (witch says should not match) must also match as it has a 7 in the middle '7123456**789**' and the length is 3. so I assumed the last one must be incorrect.

Comment: Please read the question again, more carefully. '1234567890' is **definitely** "a set of numbers except the 10 digit numbers starting with 7". It matches not because of a seven in the middle, but because it doesn't start with a seven. If you thought the problem statement was incorrect, then leave a comment on the problem asking for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get any number of digits except a string of 10 digits starting with '7'
you'd have to special case the '7'. There is really no way around it.

The fastest way is a *pure* regex solution, since the engine stays inside
running c++ engine code and does not interact with the host language.

There are two ways, either anchored or mid-string.

Anchored:  `^(?:7(?!\d{9}$)|[012345689])\d*$`
(*number string is the overall match, i.e. in capture group 0*)

```
 ^                    # Beginning of string
 (?:                  # Cluster, get first digit
      7                    # '7'
      (?! \d{9} $)         #  not followed by nine more digits
   |                     # or 
      [012345689]          # Any digit except '7' (i.e. [^\D7])
 )                    # End cluster
 \d*                  # Get optional remaining digits
 $
```

Mid-string:  `(?:^|\D)((?:7(?!\d{9}(?:\D|$))|[012345689])\d*)`
(*number string is in capture group 1*)

```
 (?: ^ | \D )         # Beginning of string or not a digit
 (                    # (1 start), The number
      (?:                  # Cluster, get first digit
           7                    # '7'
           (?!                  # Assertion, not followed by nine more digits
                \d{9} 
                (?: \D | $ )         #  (forces no more/less than nine) digits
           )
        |                     # or 
           [012345689]          # Any digit except '7' (i.e. [^\D7])
      )                    # End cluster
      \d*                  # Get optional remaining digits
 )                    # (1 end)
```

Comment: This fails on a seven followed by more nine digits--in other words, the first test case given by the OP. Fails in the sense that it is not accepted when it should.

Comment: @torazaburo - The one with the `^$` anchors, yep. Added a `$` to the assertion. The mid-string worked though. Didn't transpose correctly. Thanks!